# Prevent event firing when double click on bootstrap icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a standard card with a icon "Plus", which when clicked become an icon "minus" and lets user see content
If user clicks again on this icon "minus" the content gets hidden and the icon "plus" replace the icon "minus".

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/22354/

It works fine but the problem is that at least on my computer(chrome 40)and my mobile (android/chrome) , if I really click fast twice (like a double click), all gets "jammed up" and instead of seeing the "plus" icon when there is no content I end up seeing all the contrary I would like.

For example If I double click fast on the "plus icon", this is what I see (I should not see "this is my content when the "plus" icon is visible"):

[image]

What to do?

I tried using [a debounce script](https://gist.github.com/vincentorback/9649034) and something like the following but it did not work:

```
function debounce(fn, wait) {
  var timeout;
  return function () {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
      fn.apply(this, arguments)
    }, (wait || 1));
  }
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
      // For all major browsers, except IE 8 and earlier
      window.addEventListener('resize', debounce(function () {
        console.log('clicked');        
        clickhere();
      }, 250));

function clickhere() {
  var list = $('.cards-list')
  $('li', list).click(function(e){ 
    var card=$(this);
    $(this).find(".glyphicon").toggleClass("glyphicon-   
  minus").toggleClass("glyphicon-plus");
  });
 }
```

Current code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="operation-zone">
        <ul class="cards-list">

        <li class="card 354" data-opcode="CATIMINI26">

            <div class="card-content" id="accordion_354"> 

          <a class="card-detail-opener" id="BtnHomeOperationExpand_53313" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion_354" href="#collapseOne_354" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne_354">

            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus detail-icon_354"></i>
          </a>

          <div class="card-image card-lazy-preloader" id="accordion2">              
            <a href="/campaigns/xxxxx">
            </a><figure><a href="/campaigns/xxxxxx">   </a>         
                            <!-- responsive image -->
                            <img style="opacity: 1; display: block;" id="HPImageBanner_354" src="http://vp-eu.scene7.com/is/image/vpeu/0/00_54093_FR_brandvisualnbrandvisualfr">  
                        </figure>

                </div>



            </div> 

          <div id="collapseOne_354" class="one-column-info details panel-collapse collapse left-aligned" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" style="height: auto;">

              <div id="DivHomeOperationDescription_52850" class="description">
                  this is the content
              </div>

              <div class="card-info-actions">
                <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="/campaigns/operation-in-venicesqqsqssqsqsqsqsqsqss">go Now &gt;</a>
              </div>
          </div>



        </li>

                </ul>
```

**JS**

```
 var list = $('.cards-list')
$('li', list).click(function(e){ 
  var card=$(this);
  $(this).find(".glyphicon").toggleClass("glyphicon-minus").toggleClass("glyphicon-plus");
});
```

**CSS**

```
.cards-list {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
}
.card {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;     
    position: relative;
}

.card-content {
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
.card-image {
    vertical-align: top;
    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      color: green; 
    }
  position: relative;
  line-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 33.88%;
}
.container .jumbotron {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.card-detail-opener {  
        color: green;
      font-size: 16px;
      text-align: center;
      padding-left: 1px;
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      line-height: 27px;
      background: grey;
        position: absolute;
      z-index: 2;
      opacity: .75;
      filter: alpha(opacity=75);
      bottom: 60%;
      right: 30%;
        &:hover { background: #7E7E7E; }
        &:focus { background: #7E7E7E; }
    }

}

.card-detail-opener:link {
    color: green;

}
.glyphicon.glyphicon-remove {
    color: #333;
    &:hover { color: green; }
    &:focus {   color: green; }
}
.glyphicon.glyphicon-plus { 
     top:1px;
        color: #333;
        &:hover { color: #ffffff; }
        &:focus {   color: #ffffff; }

}
.glyphicon.glyphicon-minus {    
        top:2px;
        padding-right: 2px;//tweak to center
        color: #333;
        &:hover { color: #ffffff; }
        &:focus {   color: #ffffff; }

}


// Content of the card details in the 1-column view
.card .details {

        padding-top: 10px;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);

}
.details {
    padding-left: 1em;
}
.details .dates { 
    padding-top: 10px; 
    font-size: .8em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  color: #464650;
  margin-right: 1em;
  background-size: 90px auto !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-position-x: right !important;
  background-position-y: 0px !important;    
  margin-bottom: 8px; 
}
.details .baseline {
    color: #888;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    line-height: 0.4em;
}
.details .description {
    font-size: .65em;
    color: #464650; 
    line-height: 1.1em;
    overflow: hidden;

}
// End of content of the card details in the 1-column view
.card-info-actions {
    float: right;
    padding: 0 5px 2px 0;
    clear: both;
}
//smaller buttons for cards
.card-info-actions .btn-primary {
    font-size: 15px;
}

.card-short-info a.dateSales {
  color: #464650;
}
.info-overlay {
  display:none;
  z-index:999;
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#CCFFFFFF,endColorstr=#CCFFFFFF)\9";
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#CCFFFFFF,endColorstr=#CCFFFFFF);
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: 4px solid green;
}

.close-overlay {
  float:right;
  padding:5px;
}

.info-overlay a {
    display: block;
    line-height: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

As it's quite tricky , sharing updated jsfiddle with solution working would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<i id="icon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus detail-icon_354"></i>

$('#collapseOne_354').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
  $('#icon').removeClass('glyphicon-plus').addClass('glyphicon-minus');
});
$('#collapseOne_354').on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
  $('#icon').removeClass('glyphicon-minus').addClass('glyphicon-plus');
});
```

### [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/yz6yhe44/)

or using only CSS:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus detail-icon_354"></i>

.card-detail-opener[aria-expanded=false] i:before {
  content: '\2b';
}
.card-detail-opener[aria-expanded=true] i:before {
  content: '\2212';
}
```

### [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/o6vwnmyL/1/)

Comment: is this pure css well supported ?

Comment: Yes, it is supported by all browsers.

Comment: in the technique with pure CSS, what did you change inside the HTML, I don't manage to make it work in my app. i might be missing sth you changed in the html.

Comment: Nothing, I even copied HTML from your original JSFiddle and it works. Maybe you didn't remove JS code responsible for icon click?

Comment: mmm yes I did , strange. Now it does not change anymore from + to - (it says on aria expanded=false). i must check sth must be going wrong in my code. will update and upvote after

Comment: what's the purpose of content: '\2b'; and content: '\2212'; ?

Comment: To change the icons from plus to minus (check `bootstrap.css` file and find `.glyphicon-plus` and you will see the code).

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution might be to use a `justClicked` variable (set to `false` onload) to track whether we're dealing with a double or single-click:

1. When a click arrives, before you do anything, see whether `justClicked===true`. If so, you know that a click happened within the last second (see below), and you can `e.preventDefault()` and exit.
2. If the check above is passed, set `justClicked=true`, call `setTimeout` to execute in 1000ms and proceed with your standard click handler.
3. Any click that arrives in this period (`justClick` is `true`) will fail the check in step 1 and thus be aborted.
4. In the `setTimeout` callback, set `justClick=false`. The app is now ready to receive and handle a new click.

Comment: _1. onClick_ and _3. When a click arrives_ are the same, so what to do `set justClicked=true` or `see whether justClicked===true` ?

Comment: The check `justClicked===true` happens before you do anything. You only proceed if it's `false`. I'm changing the order of operations in my answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/DTcHh/22358/)**.

The better solution I found for this case is to use a flag variable, when the user click for the first time `clicks` will be 1 and the `setTimeout` function will be created and wait `700ms` before triggering the click event.

If another click detected before `700ms` delay (case of double click) the first timer will be cleared and the click will be not triggered :

```
var list = $('.cards-list')
var clicks=0;
var timer=null;

$('li', list).on("click", function(e){
    clicks++;  //count clicks
    var card=$(this);

    if(clicks === 1) {
      //wait a while to check if the second click will be triggered
      timer = setTimeout(function() 
      {
        card.find(".glyphicon").toggleClass("glyphicon-minus")
            .toggleClass("glyphicon-plus");

        clicks = 0; //after action performed, reset counter
      }, 700);
    }
    else 
    {
      clearTimeout(timer);    //prevent single-click action
      clicks = 0;             //after action performed, reset counter
    }
})
.on("dblclick", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  //cancel system double-click event
});
```

Hope this will helps.

Comment: Tried but same problem: if I click very fast (double click) on the plus icon, I ned up with things jammed up, that is to say with the plus icon while seeing "this is the content", which I should not see in that case

Answer (score 0):

Ok
I tried it with a different approach.

```
$('#collapseOne_354').on("hidden.bs.collapse", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
 $(".cards-list").find(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-
minus").removeClass("glyphicon-plus");
  $(".cards-list").find(".glyphicon").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
});

$('#collapseOne_354').on("shown.bs.collapse", function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $(".cards-list").find(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-
plus").removeClass("glyphicon-minus");
 $(".cards-list").find(".glyphicon").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
});
```

Please let me know if any improvement can be done.